# Formatting text width for mobile using inline styles

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have a button which renders fine on Desktop but on mobile the text wraps (http://grab.by/RkRk). Is there a way to get the text all on one line (like it is on Desktop) on mobile using only inline CSS (without using meta viewport tags or anything else on the header). Here is the HTML code for my button...

```html
 <div style="width: 180px;background-color:#cc0000; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px;padding: 10px;">
     <a href="" class="font-regular" style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial Regular', Arial; color: white; text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px;">Be thankful for everything &#187;
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use CSS media queries inline I would say no...